Equation numbering doesn't start at 1 for alignat inside minipage inside tabularray
I want to compare different ways to create environments containing equations. For this, I use a large tabularray environment containing minipage environments containing, for example array, align and alignat environments. For some reason, the equation numbering is wildly wrong. Instead of starting at 1, the equation numbering starts at 7. How can I fix this and have the equation numbering start at 1 instead of 7?
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    rows={abovesep=10pt,belowsep=10pt},
    columns={leftsep=10pt,rightsep=10pt},
    colspec={|Q[c]|},
    rowspec={|Q[m]|}
}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{alignat}{1}
a & = b \\
\end{alignat}
\end{minipage}
\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



I'd guess that tabularray uses multiple passes for trial typesetting. But I have no idea how to best fix that (as I don't use tabularray). You could use a scratch counter to store the equation counters state before \begin{tblr} and set it explicitly in your cell.

@Skillmon Thanks for the comment. Apparently there is a tabularray library that fixes this, see the accepted answer.

Use the counter library:
\documentclass[border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    rows={abovesep=10pt,belowsep=10pt},
    columns={leftsep=10pt,rightsep=10pt},
    colspec={|Q[c]|},
    rowspec={|Q[m]|}
}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{alignat}{1}
a & = b
\end{alignat}
\end{minipage}
\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



Thanks, that was simple!

@Smiley1000 You're welcome!
